# Need a little more clarification on Android screen size layouts for my app that supports Gingerbread to Jelly Bean

Tags: android, android-layout

I have read many questions regarding layouts and screen sizes for Android. I have even referred back to Android's page on it here
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#screen-independence

The problem is that there seems to be an in between that I am missing

My app supports Gingerbread to Jelly bean devices. I have it configured this way.

```
layout (for Gingerbread devices)
layout-sw320dp (for ICS/JB devies)
layout-sw600dp (for 7" tab's)
layout-sw720dp (for 10" tab's)
```

I have all my layout xmls in those folders and I tweaked them to fit the size of devices by using the graphical layout in eclipse and changing from device to device.
I thought everything was fine.

But, I seem to be missing some key devices.

For example. on my Razr it is not sizing like it's shown in eclipse graphical layout.
Razr is a 540x960 240dpi device
if i use the formula to get dp (dp = (px / dpi) * 160) i get 360dp, right?

That means it should be using the layout files from sw320dp, right? For some reason its cutting resizing some icons that are not fitting.

Then another example is a user with a HTC Thunderbolt which says he can't even load the app. A thunderbolt is 480x800 with 217dpi which would be 353dp?, is that right?
So it should be pulling resources from same sw320dp folder.
the stack trace from thunderbolt reveals this error

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f01006a a=-1}
```

that resource is  public static final int background_gb=0x7f01006a;

It's happening because its pulling layouts from the layout folder and not layout-sw320dp. I have my layouts in layout folder set to fill background with color instead of picture because i kept getting heap errors. When i test on my nexus one emulator it works fine.

So then i got to thinking maybe im not doing this correctly. I look at other dev's apks and i never even see a layout-sw320dp folder. But it seemed to do what i needed to initially. If i leave that out then my layout folder is controlling layouts for a 480x800 device all that way up to my S4's 1080x1920 device. I dont see how its possible to cover so many devices in one layout xml.

Any advice for me?

examples of problem covering everything in layout folder for phones

NexusOne
[image]

Nexus 4
[image]

Galaxy S4
[image]

Comment: Those layout folders options are available starting with 3.2 (http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts) and if I'm not mistaken Razr is a Gingerbread device, right?

Comment: I was reading that backwards. saw 3.2 was thinking 2.3. So that makes sense that gb devices will always read from layout folder. BUT both thunderbolt and razr are ICS/JB devices.

Comment: I have been playing around with dimens just after i wrote this and that may work but not sure if its best practice? I have my layout folder then for the size of margins/text/etc im referencing dimens.xml in a values-hdpi and values-xhdpi. think that is my best option?

Comment: BUT if i do that i still have issue with GB devices using a image for background. They have to use color. not sure how to segregate those out. can i do a layout-v10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Razr is a 540x960 240dpi device if i use the formula to get dp (dp = (px / dpi) * 160) i get 360dp, right?

360dp for the smallest width, yes.

> For some reason its cutting resizing some icons that are not fitting.

Your layout has a bug, then.

> It's happening because its pulling layouts from the layout folder and not layout-sw320dp. I have my layouts in layout folder set to fill background with color instead of picture because i kept getting heap errors.

Then you have a bug in your color resources, where you provided a definition for some scenarios but not all.

> But it seemed to do what i needed to initially.

I have no idea how you came to that determination.

> If i leave that out then my layout folder is controlling layouts for a 480x800 device all that way up to my S4's 1080x1920 device.

Correct.

> I dont see how its possible to cover so many devices in one layout xml.

Since they all share a similar screen size, there isn't usually a problem. Your RAZR has a ~4" screen. The HTC Thunderbolt has a ~4" screen. The Galaxy S4 has a ~4" screen. Usually, therefore, they *should* have the same layout, because they all have the same basic screen size. So long as you are using density-independent units of measure, and so long as you create fluid layouts, and so long as you have your drawables in density-specific directories, it usually "just works". This is not substantially different from writing a Web app that can support multiple browser window sizes.

> I have my layout folder then for the size of margins/text/etc im referencing dimens.xml in a values-hdpi and values-xhdpi. think that is my best option?

Use density-independent units of measure (i.e., anything but `px`), and usually you will not need density-dependent versions of `dimens.xml`. In fact, usually, your `dimens.xml` versions, if anything, match with your layout versions (e.g., you might have a `values-sw600dp` one, because you decided that your margins need to be a bit bigger with the layouts in `layouts-sw600dp`).

> i still have issue with GB devices using a image for background. They have to use color. not sure how to segregate those out

Use a color for the background on all devices. Or, fix your "heap errors". Your problem is probably not tied to OS version, as heap sizes do not usually directly vary by OS version, but rather by screen size.

Comment: Thanks for your great feedback. regarding your statement "I have no idea how you came to that determination." I have 6 devices i test on. ranging from droidx up to 10" tablet. how i had it setup worked on every device. That is why i thought i had done everything correctly. which not im finding out there was more to it. i guess my layouts are not fluid enough because i put in left/right margins with a dp value and swtich from nexus one to nex4 and its not looking the way i want it to. I guess becuase im using margins?

Comment: i updated post one with some examples. i am not using px for anything. i use sp and dp... maybe its just bad design?  But the nex4 image is my desired layout.

Comment: @Bignadad: "But the nex4 image is my desired layout" -- they all have the same general layout. I have no way of knowing specifically what it is with those images that you like and dislike. You may be better served asking one or more separate StackOverflow questions, where you provide a layout file, the screenshots, and an explanation of what is and is not working to your satisfaction, asking how one might revise the layout file or other resources to achieve that end.